# SQL Nested Execute Query

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, subquery

Since  the data type varchar has a limit of 8000 characters, I am trying to execute a SELECT statement inside an  **EXEC** statement which is as follows :

--To get a list of users from the database

```
declare @x varchar(2000)
set @x='select STRING_AGG( concat('+'''['''+',CONCAT([DatabaseUserName],'+''']'''+')),'+''','''+' )
        from(
        SELECT DP1.name AS DatabaseRoleName, isnull (DP2.name,'+ '''No members'''+') AS DatabaseUserName
        FROM sys.database_role_members AS DRM
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP1 ON DRM.role_principal_id = DP1.principal_id LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP2 ON DRM.member_principal_id = DP2.principal_id 
        WHERE DP1.type ='+ '''R'''+' 
        ) as txt'
```

--Below are the multiple ways I have tried to execute  the statement and the errors 
1)

```
exec('deny select on [schema].[TABLE] to '+ (exec  @x)) 
ERROR  = Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

2)

```
exec('deny select on [schema].[TABLE] to '+ exec N'SP_EXECUTESQL @x')
ERROR  = Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.
```

3)

```
exec('deny select on [schema].[TABLE] to '+ exec SP_EXECUTESQL @x)
ERROR
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.
```

4)

```
exec(('deny select on [schema].[Table] to '+ exec N'@x'))
Sysntax error
```

And so on, I Tried multiple combinations trying to figure out the syntax issue.

But the entire point is to not store the output of the select statement in a variable since the data can exceed the max value, rather be executed in the execute the statement and deny the permissions.

I know I can break the output of the select statement  into smaller chunks and loop over it.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

**Thank you for your time.**

Comment: Exec only support sysntax like `exec('exex @x')`.

Answer (score 0):

Exec only support nested exec like this:

```
exec( exec  @x')
```

Reference:

1. [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. [EXEC SQL overview and examples](https://www.sqlshack.com/exec-sql-overview-and-examples/)

Hope this helps.